# Browsers behaving very strangely/not working in Windows Vista SP 2

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-vista, internet-explorer

Sorry, that I'm posting this as a guest, but I couldn't log in. Maybe you can help me.

I had a virus and gave this inspiron 1525 laptop to a computer expert, who removed it. I think he reinstalled Windows, because when I got it back IE 7 was installed.

So after 3 hours I installed SP 1, SP 2, IE 9 and Google Chrome. First when there was only SP 1 and IE 7 installed, I could only use Google in IE, and I had copy the links download links of the updates (Update center didn't work) over to Google Chrome to download it there, because I couldn't do that in IE.

Now I can't use Google at all, but strangely Bing works. Also I can display certain pages, but not all (I could open StackExchange, but not the login page; that's why I'm posting this as a guest).

Another strange thing is, that now a webpage either works in both browsers (I couldn't install Opera, because the installer says it can't download the files) or in none.

It is a 32 Bit system.

It would be nice if you could help!

I hope I will be even able to post this question...

Answer (score 0):

Running the Network under Protected Mode worked for you. You discovered that only sites https were those you couldn't access.

I am suggesting to check if SSL or TSL is enabled. Renewing any Certificate might be a good idea.